# How do I upload PDF files to the cloud for free from an Express back-end?

Tags: node.js, express, pdf, file-upload

I am working on a book-selling site. Where the admin can upload books in PDF format and the users can read the pdf and they can also download it. I am using the MERN stack for this project. For uploading pdf files, I tried Cloudinary. But it doesn't allow me to redirect to the secure_url. It requires a paid subscription. My client doesn't want to do that.

So please tell me if there is a way to upload pdf files and get them as an HTTP URL. So I can store the URL in the DB and show it on the front-end.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is object storage. The best examples are AWS S3, Backblaze B2 etc.
Storage is a commodity and no respectable provider will give you that for free. However, many do provide a free tier where some amount of storage is free and anything post that is at a cheap, fixed-rate / GB

Once you have an S3 provider, you can use packages like [multer-S3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer-s3) to upload files and get a URL back
However, along with fees for storage, providers also charge fees per every GET or POST request, so if you have a lot of users accessing the files and frequently downloading, it might be worth looking into a CDN like Cloudflare to serve from cache instead of a new request every time.